# Unable to stop one-off notification?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, notifications, nsnotificationcenter

Ok, feeling pretty stupid here - but for some reason I just can't get my object to stop receiving notifications!

I've got a very basic setup in my `init:` method that's supposed to listen for the first notification and stop listening when received the first time. The `init:` methods is definitely called just once.

The issue is that **it keeps receiving notifications after the first one**:

```
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:kMyNotification
                                                     object:nil
                                                      queue:nil
                                                 usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note)
                                                           {

                                                              [NSLog(@"Got here"); 
                                                              [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                                                                              name:kMyNotification
                                                                                                            object:nil];
                                                           }];
```

Any ideas why the `removeObserver:name:object:` call doesn't seem to have any effect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
__block id observer = [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:kMyNotification
                                                 object:nil
                                                  queue:nil
                                             usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note)
                                                       {

                                                          [NSLog(@"Got here"); 
                                                          [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:observer
                                                                                                          name:kMyNotification
                                                                                                        object:nil];
                                                       }];
```

Comment: Indeed, the point is that you need to remove an observer registered for the block based callback using the id returned when the observer was registered. You can't mix the old and new add/remove methods.